# when i push to a remote repository in lightsail, git push is successfull but the source code is not there

Tags: git

I am trying to use AWS lightsail as my backend node.js server.
I want to automate deploy process. So I created a git repository in /home/bitnami/myproject.git with `git init myproject.git --bare`

I also added a file in `/hooks` directory, so that it will extract the source code. But this part is not working. Here is what I did:
`cat > post-receive` in `hooks` directory.(I also tried with the filename as `post-receive.sample`)
Below is what I entered in `post-receive` file

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/home/bitnami/my-repo --git-dir=/home/bitnami/myproject.git checkout -f
```

Then, I changed the permission of the new file with `chmod +x post-receive` and created the `my-repo` directory at `/home/bitnami`.

Then from my local machine I pushed to this repo. There was no error. When I go to remote server's `/home/bitnami/myproject.git` directory and type `git log, it gives me all the past git commit logs. So the connection seems working fine. But despite adding the hook file I cannot find the source code anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

- adding an echo to your hook script, just to confirm it is running as expecting after a push
- add a path for the checkout: `checkout -f -- .`